# Retrieve free[guest] users from Notion via API

Tags: notion-api

Is there any way to retrieve 'guests' along with the paying users from my workspace? According to the documentation of the 'get users' endpoint, it seems not possible. In the case of my use, it would be very helpful. Is there any implementation forecast?

I did use the endpoint and didn't receive the guest users.